# I am getting following error while configuring office365 mail on contact us form in laravel 7. please anyone can

Tags: php, email, laravel

Swift_TransportException (554)
Expected response code 250 but got code "554", with message "554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Cannot submit message. 0.35250:0A004D89, 1.36674:0A000000, 1.61250:00000000, 1.45378:02000000, 1.44866:5C1D0000, 1.36674:0E000000, 1.61250:00000000, 1.45378:611D0000, 1.44866:00020000, 16.55847:830F0000, 17.43559:0000000024020000000000000000000000000000, 20.52176:140FE58B1600103100000000, 20.50032:140FE58B7E17000000000000, 0.35180:140FE58B, 255.23226:0A004F89, 255.27962:0A000000, 255.27962:0E000000, 255.31418:0A005089, 0.35250:1F001432, 1.36674:32000000, 1.61250:00000000, 1.45378:02000000, 1.44866:01000000, 16.55847:69000000, 17.43559:0000000038030000000000000100000000000000, 20.52176:140FE58B16000000A1220000, 20.50032:140FE58B7E17702003000136, 0.35180:D2220000, 255.23226:53000000, 255.27962:32000000, 255.17082:DC040000, 0.27745:58000000, 4.21921:DC040000, 255.27962:FA000000, 255.1494:5D000000, 0.38698:05000780, 0.37692:01000000, 0.37948:24000100, 5.33852:00000000534D545000000100, 7.36354:0100000000000109302E3330, 4.56248:DC040000, 7.40748:010000000000010B3A346335, 7.57132:00000000000000003838302D, 1.63016:32000000, 4.39640:DC040000, 8.45434:C510E24D7698B44BBA8449F5A157D31C02000000, 5.10786:0000000031352E32302E333034352E3031343A534C32505230364D42333234343A34633565323036622D376634632D343838302D613233332D62363761343132623639336100201000000000,

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information available i think the error occurs because of a different FROM address and the Office 365 e-mail on the used account.

Comment: Thanks for your response... actually i have changed .env credentials, and mail.php. i have tried with same email in FROM address as well.